# JSON not displaying with error in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm looking to display Json from a url (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MSyA8CBZ). Then, I want the "steamid" to be displayed. Currently, I am using this code, but it's not working:

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MSyA8CBZ');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->response->players->steamid; 
?>
```

I get the error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/u434538987/public_html/testjson.php on line 4` What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you what is wrong?

Comment: `players` is an array, so it should be `$obj->response->players[0]->steamid;`

Comment: @putvande Yup! That fixed it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `players` is an array, is you could have seen if you had done `print_r($obj)` or even saw what the URL you load produced. So you should do :

```
$obj->response->players[0]->steamid;
```